# Prove $\frac {1}{1\cdot2} - \frac {1}{2\cdot3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot4}-\cdots = \ln 2 - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

Please help me with this problem.

I have figured out the $n^{th}$ term as $\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$. How do I proceed ?

Comment: You're abusing notation by using the $\infty$ sign there.

Comment: It's $(-1)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ and that $$\ln2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$$ Also, as stated, the right hand side should be $2\ln 2-1$, not $\ln2 -1$

Comment: are you sure it's $2ln2 -1$ , the answer key(from the book from which I asked this) says it's $ln2 -1$

Comment: @ajay. There is a typo in your book (ome more in textbooks !!). Eric Naslund gave the right answer, be sure.